Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
I want to say that I am unable to install or remove any package through sudo apt. Whenever I tried to install or remove any package just like this sudo apt install perl-base it shows an error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
perl-base is already the newest version (5.34.0-3ubuntu1.3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjsoncpp25 librhash0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cmake-data
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
26 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,913 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: not found
Setting up systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.12) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst: 62: addgroup: not found
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried to fix this using sudo apt --fix-broken install but still same issue persists
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjsoncpp25 librhash0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cmake-data
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cmake-data
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
26 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,913 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: not found
Setting up systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.12) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst: 62: addgroup: not found
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

When i tried to install systemd sudo apt install --reinstall systemd,
it shows the error that no filename for systemd:amd64:
Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree... Done
   Reading state information... Done
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjsoncpp25 librhash0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cmake-data
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cmake-data
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
26 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,913 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Internal Error, No file name for systemd:amd64

Please help me with this concern.
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

If this comment is meant to add more info to the question it needs to be in the question not as a comment. Please correct.

It looks to me like you need to reinstall the debconf and adduser packages, rather than the systemd package

i tried this also earlier sudo apt install --reinstall debconf but this also gave the same error

While sudo apt install --reinstall adduser gave this error:  dpkg: error processing package adduser (--configure):  installed adduser package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:  systemd depends on adduser; however:   Package adduser is not configured yet.                                dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Does dpkg itself still work? Can you run sudo dpkg --configure --pending for example?

No, dpkg is not working

sudo dpkg --configure --pending gave multiple errors with this at the end Errors were encountered while processing:  adduser  openssh-server  linux-firmware  cups-bsd  systemd  pulseaudio  cups-daemon  systemd-timesyncd  udev  pkg-config  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth  systemd-hwe-hwdb  gdm3  libpam-systemd:amd64  systemd-oomd  nvidia-settings  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic  ubuntu-pro-client  ubuntu-pro-client-l10n  snapd  systemd-sysv  cups-core-drivers  cups  libnss-systemd:amd64  ubuntu-advantage-tools  initramfs-tools 

Someone, please help, it's a little urgent. My all work has been pending as I can't use the system due to this issue.
